# Compiling PipelineDB on RaspberryPi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi2, pipelinedb

I'm trying to compile PipelineDB on a RasberryPi 2 running Raspbian.
I followed the instructions and installed ZeroMQ. I get this error:

```
In file included from ../../../../src/include/pgstat.h:18:0,
                 from brin.c:29:
../../../../src/include/pipeline/scheduler.h:53:2: error: unknown type name ‘pg_atomic_uint64’
  pg_atomic_uint64 generation;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: It would be useful if you could show at what stage this error occurs, be more explicit, explain exactly what you did?  That'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture likely does not support 64-bit atomic operations, which PipelineDB requires. See https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/blob/master/src/include/port/atomics.h#L61

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the platform to give you a definitive answer there. You may even be able to get it to compile by upgrading your version of gcc. You can also feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/issues) and our team will get around to taking a closer look at this :)

Comment: i tried to compile PipelineDB on RPi3 and i got the same error. I've installed openSUSE to have a fully working 64bit OS. Any Ideas? I've tried to upgrade gcc but without the normal gcc from repos i can't configure.